# how to declare list of names in coreData and load that into an array?

Tags: ios

i declared an array as "ArtistNames".i have to load this array with 5 artist names.i need to load the artist names from coreData. Pls..help me how to declare 5 names in coreData and how to load that names in my array.

Comment: Do U already have functional database, and those records in it?

Comment: no dude..i dont know how to make database and insert records in it..that i am searching in google

Answer (score -1):

```
// Fetch objects with a predicate
+(NSMutableArray *)searchObjectsForEntity:(NSString*)entityName withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate andSortKey:(NSString*)sortKey andSortAscending:(BOOL)sortAscending andContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    // Create fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    // If a predicate was specified then use it in the request
    if (predicate != nil)
        [request setPredicate:predicate];

    // If a sort key was passed then use it in the request
    if (sortKey != nil) {
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey ascending:sortAscending];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }

    // Execute the fetch request
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

    // If the returned array was nil then there was an error
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil)
        NSLog(@"Couldn't get objects for entity %@", entityName);

    // Return the results
    return mutableFetchResults;
}
```

You can use this helper method with desired parameters.

Update: After reading the comments. First you need something like this http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started then you can use above method for fetching the items.